# How to login as different users in samba?

Tags: windows, samba, windows-10, samba4

I am able to setup a samba shares shared among 400 users on ubuntu 20 as file server. As a part of policy after any user have completed his/her work they disconnect from share. The problem arises for some users who share computers. For these users the user who started the computer is able to login to samba successfully but subsequent users cannot login the share without reboot. All these computers run on Windows 10 & 11 OSs.

I have tried `netuse */delete` on client computers' command prompt but with no help. Can anyone guide me what I am missing?

Comment: `users cannot login`. Probably need more information than that. Like the words and numbers that appear when opening the drive in Windows Explorer, events in the event log on the client and hopefully the server.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks, I'll try to update the question with specific details by Monday.

Comment: net use has the ability to use /u:username here for a specific user